# Why a pdf document with embedded fonts can be copied but is not searchable in pdf reader

Tags: pdf, searchable

I am writing a pdf files with embedded subset fonts. As required, I am including the ToUnicode and CIDSet objects.  To test, I created a simple PDF with two Hebrew characters. I can select the two characters and copy to the clipboard, and paste it properly into another application such as Word.  But I am not able to search for a word containing these two characters.  Adobe Reader (or Acrobat) displays the message that the word was not found.  So in essence, I have created a PDF document which can be copied properly, but is not searchable. Any idea what I might be missing when creating the document?

Additional information:
1. The file in question is a minimal file with just two characters. I have tested with many such files in many different languages including English.  None of the files are searchable.
2. Curiously, if I search for the letter 'e', Adobe reader highlights an incorrect word, even if the letter 'e' does not exists in the file.
3. Adobe acrobat is also not able to search within this file, however when I save the file to another disk file, the saved file now is searchable.  I confirmed that the major objects such as the font-file, ToUnicode object, CID object, and the font description objects are the same in the saved file.  However, one of the font object is brought up closer to the top of the file.
4. FoxIt is able to search these files properly.

Relevant PDF objects:

```
5 0 obj
```

<>

stream

```
    q 0.750000 0 0 0.750000 0.000000 792.000000 cm 

    q q q 0.160000 0.000000 0.000000 0.160000 0.000000 0.000000 cm 

    BT /F0 100.000000 Tf 0 g 750.000000 -690 Td[<02B0>] TJ 35.000000 0 Td[<02B9>] TJ ET Q

    Q 

    Q

    Q
```

endstream

endobj

10 0 obj

<>

endobj

11 0 obj

<> /FontDescriptor 10 0 R/Subtype/CIDFontType2/Type/Font>>

endobj

12 0 obj

<>

endobj

8 0 obj

<>

stream

```
    /CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin

    12 dict begin

    begincmap

    /CIDSystemInfo

    << /Registry (Adobe)

    /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def

    /CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def

    /CMapType 2 def

    1 begincodespacerange

    <0000> <FFFF>

    endcodespacerange

    3 beginbfchar

    <0000> <0000>

    <02B0> <05E0>

    <02B9> <05E9>

    endbfchar

    endcmap

    CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop

    end

    end
```

endstream

endobj

Comment: Please share the PDF (e.g. via a dropbox or googledrive share), not mere excerpts.

Comment: That been said, using **Td** to introduce a horizontal shift may be a bad idea: that operator is specified as *Move to the start of the next line,* Thus, any PDF processor may interpret that **Td** as line break even though there is no vertical shift.

Comment: Please download the pdf from:  www.subsystems.com/temp/test.pdf

Comment: As per the Td issue, when I save this pdf from Acrobat or FoxIt, both generate the same sequence and both work properly.  The copy/paste from this PDF (from Acrobat or FoxIt) also work properly.  Also,  the search fails even when I search for one of the characters. So your point is well taken, but it does not seem to be the cause of the current problem.

Comment: The two character in the file can be entered for the search by selecting the Hebrew keyboard from the taskbar and typing the letter 'a' or 'b'.

Comment: If I copy/paste the characters into the search tool then Acrobat X for Windows is able to find the text. FWIW the text in the search tool looks the same as the text in the document, and the copy/pasted text in another application. DO you see the correct text in the search tool when you enter it from the keyboard ?

Comment: Just like @KenS I had no problem searching the characters, neither in Acrobat 9 nor in Reader XI. As I have not installed a Hebrew keyboard, I tried it both using the characters copied from the document and also using  'ש' and then 'נ' copied from a Unicode table.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure I installed the Hebrew keyboard. No problem here either, 'ab' turned 'שנ' and could properly be found.

Comment: I am using Acrobat XI Pro on Windows 8.  Just to assure you that I am not seeing things, this problem was first reported by my customer, and I was to reproduce it.  What happens if you search for the English letter 'e'.  For me, the two Hebrew letters can selected.  The same happens when I search for one of these English letters:  d, i, n, o, p, r,  t, y, I, N, R, T and Y.

Comment: Here is another English PDF generated using the same logic:  www.subsystems.com/temp/test_en.pdf.  It has one English line:  'This is a test line'.  When I search for "This', I find it.  But I can not find the other words.  Also, when I search for the letter 'e', 'This' can selected.

Comment: I am able to confirm the problem when using Reader 9 on 2008 Server, Reader XI on 2012 Server, Acrobat XI on Windows8 and Reader 9 on WinXP.  The problem is always reproducible when searching the test_en.pdf file (http://www.subsystems.com/temp/test_en.pdf) for any word other than the first word.  Sometime the first word is searchable, so the test.pdf sometimes works as it contain only one word.

Comment: I've been testing only on Windows 7. I'll check later on Win8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In short

The problem is due to identical PDF **ID**s used for different documents.

### In detail

Adobe Reader / Acrobat seem to cache search information for documents identifying the document by its **ID**. Some of the OP's documents seem to have the same **ID**, at least the two sample files do:

```
/ID[<754DC77D28E62763C4916970D595A10F><754DC77D28E62763C4916970D595A10F>]
```

Thus, search information from earlier viewed PDFs with that ID was used when the OP tried to search his [test.pdf](http://www.subsystems.com/temp/test.pdf). Considering this description from one of his comments:

> What happens if you search for the English letter 'e'. For me, the two Hebrew letters can selected. The same happens when I search for one of these English letters: d, i, n, o, p, r, t, y, I, N, R, T and Y.

the search information seems to have been cached for a document with Latin glyphs, Furthermore, considering this comment on [test_en.pdf](http://www.subsystems.com/temp/test_en.pdf) (a document sharing the same ID, too):

> It has one English line: 'This is a test line'. When I search for "This', I find it. But I can not find the other words.

the text of the original document seems to have started with "This" but continued differently.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Curiously though, Reader/Acrobat does not exhibit this problem  when font embedding is disabled.  Apparently, the caching is done to save on Character-code to/from Unicode required for to search when font-embedding is enabled.  The ID was generated using the output file name, for this reason it was much easily reproducible in my case since I always used the same file name for testing.  The test_en.pdf was also created with the name test.pdf, then later changed to test_en.pdf before uploading.  Now, I changed the ID logic to generate unique value, and the problem went away.

Comment: Also, I would like to up-vote your answer, but I am not allowed since I have not been much active on the forum.  Is there a way to up-vote regardless?

Comment: Well, you should be able to accept the answer. As that also gives you rep, you probably can upvote thereafter.

Comment: I accepted your answer and will up-vote when I become eligible. Thanks again!